# What is the meaning of "!." in Dart? What is the equivalent code of "!." ? -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to extend FileImage.

But I found there are some code required "non-nullable" feature:

```
  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(FileImage key, DecoderCallback decode) async {
    assert(key == this);

    final Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes();

    if (bytes.lengthInBytes == 0) {
      // The file may become available later.
      PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.evict(key);
      throw StateError('$file is empty and cannot be loaded as an image.');
    }

    return await decode(bytes);
  }
```

What is the equivalent code of "PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.evict(key);" ?

Comment: Null Safety... you're telling the IDE that variable is not null. If by any reason is actually null, you'll have a crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have:

```
int? foo = 1; // foo is nullable.
```

And when you do something like this:

```
foo!.toString();
```

You're telling the compiler that I know `foo` isn't `null`, let me proceed. So, it is equivalent to:

```
(foo as int).toString();
```

This is actually called bang operator, and in case `foo` is `null`, you get an error.

Comment: I don't know flutter *or* dart, but why `(foo as String)`? If `foo` is an `int?`, shouldn't this be `(foo as int).toString()`?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I don't know what was going on in my mind that I thought foo was `String?` when it was `int?`. Fixed the error, thanks for pointing out!